# Error when using Double.parseDouble

Tags: java

Im new to java and just wondering how do i get rid of this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at fksdfs.test1.assign(test1.java:69)
at fksdfs.test1.main(test1.java:60)
```

I'm trying to get the Value from the textfield and convert it into a double to perform calculations on but it is not working. Can anyone help me?
Sorry for the messy coding.

```
public class test1 {
    private JTextField tField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel Age = new JLabel("Age");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel Overall = new JLabel("Overall: ");
        JTextField age = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel shoot = new JLabel("Shooting: ");
        JTextField shooting = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel dribble = new JLabel("Dribbling: ");
        JTextField dribbling = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel pass = new JLabel("Passing : ");
        JTextField passing = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel defend = new JLabel("defending : ");
        JTextField defending = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel head = new JLabel("Heading : ");
        JTextField heading = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel pace = new JLabel("Pace: ");
        JTextField pacey = new JTextField(10);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(Age);
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(Overall);
        panel.add(age);
        panel.add(shoot);
        panel.add(shooting);
        panel.add(dribble);
        panel.add(dribbling);
        panel.add(pass);
        panel.add(passing);
        panel.add(defend);
        panel.add(defending);
        panel.add(head);
        panel.add(heading);
        panel.add(pace);
        panel.add(pacey);

        String age1 = textField.getText();
        String overall1 = age.getText();
        String shooting1 = shooting.getText();
        String dribbling1 = dribbling.getText();
        String passing1 = passing.getText();
        String heading1 = heading.getText();
        String defending1 = defending.getText();
        String pace1 = pacey.getText();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

    }

    public static void assign(String s) {
        Double.parseDouble(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: _"java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String"_ You can't get a more explicit message.

Comment: Can you even read _your own code_ with such formatting?

Comment: `Sorry for the terrible indenting and messy coding` - well then fix it. There is no excuse for not writing code with proper formatting.

Comment: what are you passing to assign method while calling it ?

Comment: poor indented code.First indent it then ask..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code that you've shown here ISN'T the actual code that's producing that error.  If you want the community's help finding a bug, please make sure you post the actual code that contains the actual bug.

Answer (score 3):

The code that is causing your error is not shown in your code above. It is where you call the assign method. When you are calling it, the String is empty, and so you're trying to convert `""` into a number which makes sense should throw this exception.

Note the exception message is telling you all this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String:

The String is empty -- no number in it.

> at fksdfs.test1.assign(test1.java:69)

It's occurring at line 69 of test1.java where you all assign.

The fix: don't do this, don't try to parse an empty String. Test if the String is empty first, or do your parsing in a try/catch block.

As an aside, please put in the effort to post well formatted code when asking questions here. We're volunteers and as such expect you to do put in the effort so that it isn't unduly hard to read and understand your code if you're asking us for help. Also, avoid doing all this stuff in the main method or using *static* methods such as your assign method. This method should be an instance method, and most all of your code should be in a proper OOP class. You will want to learn how to create classes and basics of Java before trying to create complex GUI's, and the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a tip for your future code...

When using GUIs and inputing code it is often better to create a pre-made exception handler for incorrect inputs. My preference would be:

```
try{
   double somethingDouble = Double.parseDouble(something.getText());
}catch(){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
   "Check input - this is supposed to be a decimal value!");
   something.setText("");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- that way you could just add the try block into an actionPerformed method and determine if the user of your product - or in this case, your code - could determine if he/she entered in valid input.

Note: place the e.printStackTrace() line after the error message in the try block